# Using Twilio Chat on iOS, is it possible to send a small amount of custom non-message data between users?

Tags: ios, twilio

We have an app built with Twilio Chat for iOS and everything is working very well.  However, we now have a requirement to invite the other chat participant to join a video room, and we would like to send the invite signal through the Twilio Chat channel that is already established (similar in functionality to the Typing signal.)

I know Push Notifications are supported by Twilio Chat, but that seems like overkill for this use case, where a simple signal is all that's needed.

**What is the easiest way to send a very small amount of non-message data between Twilio Chat channel participants?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you send [a message with Twilio Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/messages) you can also set an `Attributes` field which can contain JSON. You can then use this to signal that the message is not for printing on the page, but a service message or invite. You will then need to updated your UI to read the attributes of a message and decide whether to display it or use it to create the Video chat.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I appreciate the quick and accurate response. This method would work, and I realized I could also set member userinfo attributes, which would trigger a callback on the other end as well - that method being slightly different in that a message would not need to be sent in order to signal the other participant.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I was of help. Hope the rest of the feature goes well for you!